# Is the structure of this sentence correct? "She was awarded with a medal and a trophy, giving her the rights to brag."

Tags: grammar, sentence-patterns

> "She was awarded with a medal and a trophy, giving her the rights to brag."

Often when I use Microsoft word, I get a squiggly line if I wrote sentence structures like the example given. The program recommended that I added 'and' before 'giving' which did not sound right to me. I've seen similar structures when reading novels and I wonder if this kind of structure has some grammatical restrictions?

Comment: Your sentence is fine. I see what MS Word's grammar checker is trying to do, but English is so flexible that I don't see any computerised grammar checker being 100% any time soon.

Answer (score -3):

how about 
"She was awarded with a medal and a trophy, and that gave here right to brag"

or
 "She was awarded with a medal and a trophy, which gave here the right to brag"

or

"A recipient of medal and a trophy, she has the right to brag"